# how to get hashed url from ajax response of a form submit?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using an exchange plugin on wordpress, and I want to make the whole process of bidding ajax; so when submitting one of the forms the page goes to a blank page which show something like this:

```
{"status":"success","response":"","status_code":0,"status_text":"Bid successfully created","url":"http:\/\/example.com\/step2\/hst_HH8yhuadhHFKlgij94fE4fGaw59HUmsL94j\/","account1_error":0,"account1_error_text":"","account2_error":0,"account2_error_text":"","summ1_error":0,"summ1_error_text":"","summ2_error":0,"summ2_error_text":"","summ1c_error":0,"summ1c_error_text":"","summ2c_error":0,"summ2c_error_text":"","cf":[],"cf_er":[],"cfc":[],"cfc_er":[]}
```

which seems like ajax response (or whatever, I don't know exactly)
But here's the thing, when I enter the url in this code in the address bar, it goes exactly wehere I wanted to go, so How can I somehow get this hashed url right after form submit and load the content of that page in current page using jQuery?

or just when this page loads immediately it redirects to the url in it?

or at least can you help me somehow or just put me on the right direction?

Comment: Looks like a json response to me, you just need to decode it first.

Comment: @MacroMan i guessed it was json, but the url works when it's entered in the address bar. so is there any way to get that url from page or some other way?

Comment: decode the json.... then get the url from the json object and use something like `location.href = $response.url;` in your `success:` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Capture the response to a variable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$json = json_decode(input);
```

then access the URL through that:

```
echo $json.url
```

This should be done in the script where your form is `POST` to.

**EDIT**, regarding the `POST` to `/ajax.html`, that file should contain something similar to [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-post.htm):

```
<?php
// If loop is only entered if $_POST["name"] is not empty.
// $_POST[value] comes from the POST parameters, e.g., for example.com/ajax.html?name=Nick ...
if( $_POST["name"] ) {

   $name = $_POST['name']; // ... then `echo $name` will print "Nick"
   echo "Welcome ". $name;
}
?>
```

Comment: This logic is actually better than what I suggested in the comments. +1

Comment: what would be the 'input' here? is it possible to use this code in jQuery submit function ?

Comment: The `input` would be your `POST["var"]` from the `<form>`. How do you `POST` your form off?

Comment: I dont know exactly what you mean. I'm actually making changes to a plugin that i didn't wrote. can you help me out here?

Comment: Hmm, well I see you said that this is after a `<form>` request. What does the `action` attribute of the tag say, so `<form action="x">`, what is *x*?

Comment: Okay, that's not the `action` attribute, however that does help. You're posting to a HTML page, under the root directory for your website at `/ajax.html`. This is where your response is being sent to, and that is where you need to handle it. I'll update the answer with an example of handling that.

Comment: @Komeyl94 See the answer for an example.

Comment: @Komeyl94 Please accept if it solved the question :)